# Is it possible to use a matrix INSTEAD of if statements to evaluate a value in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, conditional-statements

Okay so I have 2 data frames:

inspection_category

| inspection_category | location_code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 123 |
| B | 134 |
| D | 156 |

and

risk_status

| risk_status | location_code |
| --- | --- |
| High | 123 |
| Very High | 134 |
| Low | 156 |

Based off the inspection_category and risk_status, I need to evaluate a "risk score" for each location_code using a matrix. The matrix is as follows:

(inspection_category corresponds to the top row, while risk_status corresponds to the first column , risk_score = the cell at the intersection of inspection_category and risk_status )

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| very low | very good | good | good | moderate | poor |
| low | good | good | good | moderate | poor |
| medium | good | good | moderate | moderate | poor |
| high | moderate | moderate | moderate | poor | poor |
| very high | poor | poor | poor | poor | poor |

how do I evaluate a risk score for each location_code without writing a bunch of if statements like: if inspection_category = A and risk_status = very low, risk_score = very good. Seems like it would just be ugly and unwieldy with the amount of combos above.

Is there a way to do this by creating a matrix instead of writing if statements? If so please help! I'm stumped!

Comment: Simply `merge` the two data frames then `reshape` wide or in tidy speak `join` + `pivot_wider`. Give it a try and come back with specific issues if any.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way. First merge the two data.frames, then loop through the merged df and subset the matrix with each merged df row values.

```
mrg <- merge(inspection_category, risk_status)
apply(mrg[2:3], 1, \(inx) risk_score_mat[ inx[2], inx[1] ])
# [1] "moderate" "poor"     "moderate"
```

### Data

```
x <- '
inspection_category     location_code
A   123
B   134
D   156'
inspection_category <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
x <- '
risk_status     location_code
High    123
"Very High"     134
Low     156'
risk_status <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
x <- "  A   B   C   D   E
'Very Low'  'very good'     good    good    moderate    poor
Low     good    good    good    moderate    poor
Medium  good    good    moderate    moderate    poor
High    moderate    moderate    moderate    poor    poor
'Very High'     poor    poor    poor    poor    poor"
risk_score_mat <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)
```